# Loki :Typelist.h

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++-loki

I am trying examples of Typelist and also read the example given in following link.
 [Typelists visitor pattern example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578607/typelists-visitor-pattern-example)

But in that example they have not used the **Typelist.h** provided by loki. My question is how we can use that header file to create typelist or we have to write from scratch.

Comment: Do you have access to C++11 or are you restricted to C++03. Because TypeList is obsolete in C++11: there are much easier ways to achieve what it did.

Comment: I don't have access to C++11. is you are talking about "variadic templates" which is part of c++11